# How to highlight duplicate rows in each range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data for each month in this manner, different emp Id's for each month till now starting from the month of Jan

I want to highlight one emp Id if there is a duplicate because it was entered by wrong and should be paid once.

| Emp ID | Employee Name Month for Jan-2022 | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2122 | ABC | 1000 |
| 1898 | ACD | 2000 |
| 2122 | ABC | 1000 |
| 4466 | CAD | 4000 |
| 3432 | DAC | 5000 |

| Emp ID | Employee Name Month for Feb-2022 | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2122 | ABC | 1000 |
| 1898 | ACD | 2000 |
| 3432 | DAC | 3000 |
| 4466 | CAD | 4000 |
| 3432 | DAC | 3000 |

So in Jan Emp Id 2122 has been entered twice and needs to be highlighted while in Feb 3432 needs to be highlighted.

Presently I'm using using adjacent columns like one on D and on E with formulas like

=CEILING (COUNTA(A2:A$3)/7,1)

and

COUNTIFS(A$2:A$13,A2,D$2:D$13,D2)

The first one returns group count while the second one returns the number of each counts of emp, last I'm using in conditional formatting a formula =$E2=2 which does the work and highlights the duplicates but can I do this with one formula. Please help

Comment: couldn't you use : `Conditionnal Formatting > Highligh Cells Rules > Duplicate Values..` ?

Comment: That will highlight all the duplicates in both the range. I want to highlight duplicate in specific months

Answer (score 1):

You can use just a single extra column to determine the month and then a COUNTIFS to find your result. Assuming your table start in cell A1, use this formula in cell D2 to extract the "month label":

```
=IF(LEFT(B1,LEN("Employee Name Month for "))="Employee Name Month for ",SUBSTITUTE(B1,"Employee Name Month for ",""),D1)
```

Remember to drag it down to cover the whole list. Then apply a conditional formatting using this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<>Emp ID",A:A,A1,D:D,D1)>1
```

To be fair, the "month label" formula could be as simple as:

```
=IF(A2="Emp ID",B2,D1)
```

but the result would be uglier in my humble opinion.

---

---

---

Another possible solution would be this formula (again for cell D2):

```
=IF(A2="Emp ID",B2,IF(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,IF(LEFT(B1,LEN("Employee Name Month for "))="Employee Name Month for ",SUBSTITUTE(B1,"Employee Name Month for ",""),MID(D1,1,FIND("|",D1)-1))&"|"&A2)>0,IF(LEFT(B1,LEN("Employee Name Month for "))="Employee Name Month for ",SUBSTITUTE(B1,"Employee Name Month for ",""),MID(D1,1,FIND("|",D1)-1))&"|"&"<<<<<<<<",IF(LEFT(B1,LEN("Employee Name Month for "))="Employee Name Month for ",SUBSTITUTE(B1,"Employee Name Month for ",""),MID(D1,1,FIND("|",D1)-1))&"|"&A2))
```

It will mark any extra entry with `<<<<<<<<` while its first occurence won't be highlight.